# What is the idiomatic alternative to static mutable data?

Tags: rust, iron

I'm using the Iron framework to create a simple endpoint.  I have stateful, mutable data that the endpoint needs access to.

Here's some code that shows my intention:

```
extern crate iron;
extern crate mount;

use iron::{Iron, Request, Response, IronResult};
use iron::status;
use mount::Mount;

static mut s_counter: Option<Counter> = None;

struct Counter {
    pub count: u8
}

impl Counter {
    pub fn new() -> Counter {
        Counter {
            count: 0
        }
    }

    pub fn inc(&mut self) {
        self.count += 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    unsafe { s_counter = Some(Counter::new()); }
    let mut mount = Mount::new();
    mount.mount("/api/inc", inc);
    println!("Server running on http://localhost:3000");
    Iron::new(mount).http("127.0.0.1:3000").unwrap();
}

fn inc(req: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    let mut counter: Counter;
    unsafe {
        counter = match s_counter {
            Some(counter) => counter,
            None => { panic!("counter not initialized"); }
        };
    }
    counter.inc();
    let resp = format!("{}", counter.count);
    Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, resp)))
}
```

This code doesn't compile:

```
error: cannot move out of static item
```

I'm hoping that there is nicer way to do this, not involving any unsafe code or `static mut`.  My question is, what is the idiomatic way to accomplish this?

Comment: I was in a Situation where i needed a static module variable that comes out of functions (glium display). My idea was to have a Outer Module with a Controlling Struct, that contains this data. The problem is somehow different, but you could still think about this idea though.

Answer (score 5):

I'd highly recommend reading the entirety of [*The Rust Programming Language*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/), especially the [chapter on concurrency](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/concurrency.html). The Rust community has put a lot of effort into producing high quality documentation to help people out.

In this case, I'd probably just make the `Counter` struct an Iron [`Handler`](http://ironframework.io/doc/iron/middleware/trait.Handler.html). Then, I'd use an atomic variable inside the struct to hold the count without requiring mutablity:

```
extern crate iron;
extern crate mount;

use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering};

use iron::{Iron, Request, Response, IronResult};
use iron::status;
use mount::Mount;

struct Counter {
    count: AtomicUsize,
}

impl Counter {
    pub fn new() -> Counter {
        Counter {
            count: AtomicUsize::new(0),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut mount = Mount::new();
    mount.mount("/api/inc", Counter::new());
    println!("Server running on http://localhost:3000");
    Iron::new(mount).http("127.0.0.1:3000").unwrap();
}

impl iron::Handler for Counter {
    fn handle(&self, _: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
        let old_count = self.count.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);

        let resp = format!("{}", old_count);

        Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, resp)))
    }
}
```

Comment: So my example was a bit simplified and I couldn't  get away with an atomic variable in reality. The actual strict I'm using represents an emulated 6502.

Comment: @w.brian Then a [`Mutex`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) or a [`RwLock`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html) plus an [`Arc`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html)? Or maybe a [`channel`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html)? Two out of the three of those are documented in the book chapter I linked.